# Add n (empty) rows per group_by

Tags: r

I want to 'unaggregate' rows of data.

For example, I want to turn this table

```
  ID Allocated Remaining
1  A         2         4
2  B         1         2
3  C         0         1
```

into this table:

```
   ID Sourced
1   A       1
2   A       1
3   A       0
4   A       0
5   A       0
6   A       0
7   B       1
8   B       0
9   B       0
10  C       0
```

I want to do this by grouping the rows by ID and then adding a number of rows for, first, every allocated point and, second, for every remaining data point.

Something like:

```
df <- df %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   do(add_row(.))
```

But I want a specific amount of rows to be added per group.

Does anybody know how to tackle this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID)  %>%
  transmute(
    Sourced=list(c(rep(1,Allocated), rep(0,Remaining)))
    ) %>%  
  unnest
```

---

```
  ID    Sourced
   <chr>   <dbl>
 1 A           1
 2 A           1
 3 A           0
 4 A           0
 5 A           0
 6 A           0
 7 B           1
 8 B           0
 9 B           0
10 C           0
```

Comment: That works great. But I would use `ungroup` instead of `unnest`.

Answer (score 0):

`pmap_dfr` iterates through rows and each row is input to function `tibble` (`..1` is the first value, `..2` the second and `..3` the third). After calculation on all rows is done it binds them.

```
df %>%
  pmap_dfr(~tibble(ID = ..1, Sourced = c(rep(1, ..2), rep(0, ..3))))
```

Comment: How does this function work?

Comment: it iterates through rows and each row is input to function (..1 is first value, ..2 second and ..3 thrid). After calculation on all rows is done it binds them.

Answer (score 0):

Since `summarise` can return more than one row you may use -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(Sourced = rep(c(1, 0), c(Allocated, Remaining)), .groups = 'drop')

#   ID    Sourced
#   <chr>   <dbl>
# 1 A           1
# 2 A           1
# 3 A           0
# 4 A           0
# 5 A           0
# 6 A           0
# 7 B           1
# 8 B           0
# 9 B           0
#10 C           0
```

Answer (score 0):

We may use `uncount`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
    uncount(Allocated + Remaining) %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    transmute(Sourced = +(row_number() <= first(Allocated))) %>% 
    ungroup
# A tibble: 10 × 2
   ID    Sourced
   <chr>   <int>
 1 A           1
 2 A           1
 3 A           0
 4 A           0
 5 A           0
 6 A           0
 7 B           1
 8 B           0
 9 B           0
10 C           0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "B", "C"), Allocated = 2:0, Remaining = c(4L, 
2L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3"))
```